# Copying text from images/videos... nope most of the time

Tags: macos, ios, ipados

I have a 9.7” iPad Pro with iOS 16.5.

I have watched Apple presentation saying I could copy texts from videos, photos, etc, using iOS even using native apps, like the youtube.app. NOPE!

I can copy texts on Preview (macOS) and on Photos (iOS on iPhone) but not on Photos (iPadOS). Copy texts from videos? Just on macOS, from Safari and very poorly.

Am I missing something or this is what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iPad (iPad Pro 9.7") *doesn't support Live Text* as it's not present in [Models that support Live Text, Visual Look Up, and lifting a subject from the background](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/ipad/aside/ipad06376462/16.0/ipados/16.0):

> - iPad mini (5th generation and later)
> - iPad (9th generation and later)
> - iPad Air (3rd generation and later)
> - iPad Pro 11-inch (all generations)
> - iPad Pro 12.9-inch (3rd generation and later)

<sup>Disclaimer: ***This is the full list, there's nothing more in it.***</sup>

---

For the Youtube video where text could not be detected, maybe the video contains text which isn't very "lisible" by Live Text, that could explain why it doesn't detect text there. Try downloading the video to your photo library and see if it works better.

Comment: AHHHHHHHH! I was finding it very strange. Thanks. But is live text that bad on macOS on youtube?

Comment: @Duck Not sure but I'd say that it depends on the video quality. If the device can recognize the text or not. Maybe if you download the video full resolution, it'll work better?